# Oracle column referenced by two foreign keys

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I haven't tried this yet, it's part of a 90+ tables schema that I'm rebuilding and I was wondering if the logic was right. 
I have two tables which contain data and a third one that joins PKs from them:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
    USER_ID NUMBER(9),
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(9),
    DESK_ID NUMBER(9),
    FULLNAME VARCHAR2(12),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE1 PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, DESK_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2
(
    USER_ID NUMBER(9),
    BUILDING_ID NUMBER(9),
    PARKING_ID NUMBER(9),
    LICENSE_PLATE VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE2 PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, BUILDING_ID, PARKING_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE3
(
    USER_ID NUMBER(9),
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(9),
    DESK_ID NUMBER(9),
    BUILDING_ID NUMBER(9),
    PARKING_ID NUMBER(9),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE3 PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, DESK_ID, BUILDING_ID, PARKING_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE3_T1 FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, DESK_ID) REFERENCES TABLE1(USER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, DESK_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE3_T2 FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID, BUILDING_ID, PARKING_ID) REFERENCES TABLE2(USER_ID, BUILDING_ID, PARKING_ID)
);
```

Is it right? Can the same column TABLE3.USER_ID be part of two FKs?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, even with the same column list.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(C1   NUMBER   PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE T2
(C1   NUMBER   PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE T3
(C1   NUMBER   PRIMARY KEY);
```

Populate T1 and T2 with some values:

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(2);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(3);
```

Create two identical constraints from T3 to T1 and T2:

```
ALTER TABLE T3
ADD CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (C1) REFERENCES T1(C1);

ALTER TABLE T3
ADD CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY (C1) REFERENCES T2(C1);
```

And now...

```
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES(1);   -- Succeeds (1 is in both T1 and T2)
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES(2);   -- Fails (2 is only in T1 and violates FK2)
```

Clean your environment:

```
DROP TABLE T3 PURGE;
DROP TABLE T1 PURGE;
DROP TABLE T2 PURGE;
```

I hope this helps you...